# MKS error- pipe-authd

Tags: vsphere, esxi

It's about a day that I have this problem with my machines. My `ESXi is 6.0`. 
When i open the console of my machines, it shows the below error.
First the error was `"unable to connect to mks:internal error",` but after I opened the `port 902` this error appeared.

```
"Unable to connect to MKS:Could not connect to pipe \\.\pipe\vmware-authdpipe w"
```

Now I do not know what to do with this. I have tried a lot.
Could anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance
Ashkan

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always DNS. Check if you can resolve the hostname of the host the VM sits on. Add it to your hosts file if you have to. I've had issues where only one of the resolvers could resolve it, so that explained an intermittent issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the DNS explain that you said. Would you explain it more. To which host file I should add it?
Thanks

Comment: The system you are attempting to console from, usually your own desktop, it needs to resolve the hostname of the esxi host that contains the VM you are attempting to console. If those hostnames are not able to be resolved by your systems dns resolvers, you can modify the hosts file on your computer so that it can resolve the hostname of all the hosts in vcenter or the standalone esxi host(s).